# the effect of empty lines on training a FastText model

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I am trying to train a FastText model. The format of the file which the model is trained on is in a way that each line contains a sentence and sentences are separated from each other by a newline character. However, due to preprocessing, sometimes all words from a sentence are deleted, so the line becomes empty. As a result, out of 7 million lines, 72 of them are empty. I want to know whether this can cause a problem to how well the model is built. Does it make any difference? Does FastText ignore these empty lines or take them into account and as a result the model will not be trained well?

Comment: Why not just remove empty lines entirely then such that you won't have to worry about side effects?

Comment: As @StefanB notes, they should be easy to remove. But also: did you try it and encounter any problems? Or perhaps, on a toy-sized fragment of your dataset, with some reald data and a few blank lines? (I'm pretty sure it won't cause any problems, but it's easy enough to make the issue moot or just try it and see what happens.)